# How does %.*Lf work in C?

Tags: c

I have a school assignment that consists in creating a program that determines an approximation of a square root, and one of the requirements of it is that the user must specify how many decimal places it wants it to display. This is the solution I found in this forum:

`printf("Sqrt of %d is %.*Lf",number,decimals,value);`

I looked around and I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: `man 3 printf`?

Comment: 'lf' is a conversation specifier for scanf() and printf ()  input, which stands for 'long float'.  The * is some integer representing decimal precision.  For example, %4lf will read in or print the integral with 4-places following.

Comment: wait, you have two conversion specifier and three argument? .... yes,indeed, that's not a typo, try to find the reason behind it, you'll get the point.

Answer (score -1):

%d is number type int

%.* is decimals(decimal places) the * is replaced with decimals

L is Long

f is Double

%.2f would round to two decimal places of type double.